# Linked list with removal function in Rust

Tags: linked-list, rust

I know there are other structures which are better than the linked list, but I want to implement a singly linked list which has a `remove` function for study.

After struggling for a few hours, I wrote this code.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;

struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(elem: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            elem: elem,
            next: None,
        }))
    }
}

pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

impl<T: Eq> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let new_head = Node::new(elem);
        match self.head.take() {
            Some(old_head) => {
                new_head.borrow_mut().next = Some(old_head);
                self.head = Some(new_head);
            }
            None => {
                self.head = Some(new_head);
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn remove(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let mut head = self.head.clone().unwrap();
        if head.borrow().elem == elem {
            self.head = head.borrow().next.clone();
            return;
        }

        loop {
            let next = head.borrow().next.clone();
            match next {
                None => return,
                Some(ref node) => {
                    if node.borrow().elem == elem {
                        head.borrow_mut().next = node.borrow().next.clone();
                    }
                    head = node.clone();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.push(3);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(1);
    list.remove(2);
    let head = list.head.unwrap().clone();
    assert_eq!(head.borrow().elem, 1);
    let next = head.borrow().next.clone().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(next.borrow().elem, 3);
}
```

To iterate this list, I implemented a iterator.

```
pub struct Iter<T> {
    next: Link<T>
}

impl<T> Iterator for Iter<T> {
    type Item = Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let next = self.next.clone();
        let next_next = next.clone();
        self.next = match next_next {
            Some(node) => {
                node.borrow().next.clone()
            }
            None => {
                None
            }
        };
        next
    }
}

impl<T: Eq> List<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter { next: self.head.clone() }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.push(3);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(1);
    list.remove(2);

    let mut it = list.iter();
    let next_node = it.next().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(next_node.borrow().elem, 1);
    let next_node = it.next().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(next_node.borrow().elem, 3);
    let next_node = it.next();
    assert_eq!(next_node.is_none(), true);
}
```

I'm not sure this code is good, because I think

- there are too many `clone()` or `borrow()` calls.
- code is long and not simple. (is using `Rc` and `RefCell` good?)

Are there easier or simpler ways?

Even if this code is not so bad, are there weak or dangerous points?

Answer (score 1):

1. Read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/).
2. Your code has **compilation errors** with Rust 1.18.0.

   ```
   error[E0446]: private type `Node<T>` in public interface
     --> src/main.rs:82:5
      |
   82 |     type Item = Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>;
      |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
   ```
3. I derive `Debug` on almost every struct.
4. `push` can have all conditionals removed from it because doing
   nothing is the same as setting `None` as the next value.
5. `remove` panics when called on a newly-created list.
6. pushing 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 and then removing 1 results in the list `2->1->1` which doesn't seem any flavor of correct. I assume you wanted to remove the first match.
7. It's way easier to get the code right when it operates on the same level of abstraction. I've created a method that removes on a `&mut Link<T>` because that's the shared type between `List` and `Link`.
8. Honestly, it's also easier to get this right with recursive code as well.
9. Doesn't make sense to return the `Rc<RefCell<...>>` as the iterator type - people care about the values, not the collection.
10. Can simplify the iterator by just taking the value out of the iterator state and putting a new value in sometimes.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(elem: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            elem: elem,
            next: None,
        }))
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
}

impl<T: Eq> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let new_head = Node::new(elem);
        new_head.borrow_mut().next = self.head.take();
        self.head = Some(new_head);
    }

    pub fn remove(&mut self, elem: T) {
        fn remove_inner<T: Eq>(node: &mut Link<T>, elem: T) {
            if let Some(ref mut n) = node.clone() {
                if elem == n.borrow().elem {
                    *node = n.borrow_mut().next.take();
                    return
                }

                remove_inner(&mut n.borrow_mut().next, elem);
            }
        }

        remove_inner(&mut self.head, elem)
    }
}

fn main1() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.push(3);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(1);
    list.remove(2);
    let head = list.head.unwrap().clone();
    assert_eq!(head.borrow().elem, 1);
    let next = head.borrow().next.clone().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(next.borrow().elem, 3);

    let mut list = List::new();
    list.remove(2);

    let mut list = List::new();
    list.push(1);
    list.push(1);
    list.push(1);
    list.push(1);
    list.push(2);
    list.remove(1);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}

pub struct Iter<T> {
    next: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for Iter<T> {
    type Item = Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.next.take() {
            Some(next) => {
                self.next = next.borrow().next.clone();
                Some(next)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Eq> List<T> {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter { next: self.head.clone() }
    }
}

fn main2() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.push(3);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(1);
    list.remove(2);

    let mut it = list.iter();
    let next_node = it.next().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(next_node.borrow().elem, 1);
    let next_node = it.next().unwrap();
    assert_eq!(next_node.borrow().elem, 3);
    let next_node = it.next();
    assert_eq!(next_node.is_none(), true);
}

fn main() {
    main1();
    main2();
}
```

Frankly, I don't know *why* you used `Rc` and `RefCell` — they aren't needed to implement a singly linked list. There's no need for complicated shared ownership (no need for `Rc`) and there's no need for interior mutability (no need for `RefCell`).

Comment: Thank you for careful review. I think remove function need to change the `next` in `Node`, so I used `RefCell`. Can I implement it without `RefCell`?